# Eclipse EMF. Generate a .JPG file from aird at each commit

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, cicd, eclipse-emf

I would like to know if there is a small tutorial or quick instructions to make gitlab generate a capture of the aird/ecore file in the form of jpg file each time I push my model.

I know I would set a CICD pipeline in gitlab but dont know where to start.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Abdelghani

Comment: Not sure but perhaps Eclipse Sirius offers a way to export a diagram to JPG by using their APIs.

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro. Any link to a documentation where I can start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have an Ecore metamodel (.ecore), with a graphical representation (.aird). This graphical representation comes from EcoreTools which is based on Eclipse Sirius.

Sirius does provide an API to export a diagram as an image, start looking around this: https://git.eclipse.org/c/sirius/org.eclipse.sirius.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.sirius.ui/src/org/eclipse/sirius/ui/tools/api/actions/export/ExportAction.java